# Tabulator - Initial Filter On Windows User Identity Name

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have a tabulator which needs to be filtered every time it renders.

The data in the tabulator has 3 columns coming in from an api:

```
 domainaccount (SamAccount Name),

 reportname (name of ssrs report),

 requiredstat (status true/false)
```

My tabulator:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     // tabulator start
   var tabledata = new Tabulator("#reps_byuser_tabulator", {
    //persistence:true, //enable table persistence
    resizableColumns:false,
    headerSort:false,
    reactiveData: true,
    height:"100%",
    ajaxURL: "api/ssrs_reps_status_",
    
    initialFilter:[
        {field:"domainaccount", type:"=", value: "NLHNET\\myaccountname}
    ],
            
  columns:[

    {title:"Windows Account Name", 
        field:"domainaccount", 
        frozen:true,
        width:200
       }        
     ]
    }
   );
```

I need the initial filter to work with:

```
 User.Identity.Name
```

To filter the tabulator data by using the currently logged in user
against the field in the tabulator:

```
 field:"domainaccount"
```

I have tried a function to use in an onload event. But the DOM does not know about the tabulator until after, meaning the function cannot filter anything until tabledata has something to use:

```
 // define the default filter to only show reports that a user is subscribed to by passing in their user name
function filterReps() {
    tabledata.addFilter("Domainaccount", "=", User.Identity.Name);
    alert("showing reports subscribed to by : ", User.Identity.Name);
}
```

Question:

What is the best method to filter the tabulator to the currently logged in user?

Thanks.